Grouping in sap.m.table
I want to implement the following solution: https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/d344c5aa5c81483482dbbed5b3abb142
So, I have a sap.m.Table and want to add a grouping for a specific column, as in the example on the link. In my table, I have 3 columns which are displayed correctly. One of these columns I want to use for grouping like in the link.
I added the column in the groupBy property of the Sorter grouping. Still, the table does not group like in the example. I guess I am missing some other properties? The documentation is very weak. I can't find any help on the internet.

If the question is about the Neptune Software Development Tool for designing, please reach out to the Neptune Software support.

would you mind sharing your current XML coding of your sap.m.Table?
Usually I achieve grouping like this:
<Table items="{path: '/YourPath', sorter: { path: 'SorterColumn', group: true} }">


I am actually using the Neptune Software Development Tool for Designing. So no XML.

@Adriatic Then the question is off-topic in SO. Please reach out to the Neptune support.
